# defining constants in typescript (ionic application)

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

In my Ionic application I am defining constants as

```
//constants.ts
export var CONSTANTS = {
 API_ENDPOINT: 'http://localhost:3000/'
};
```

and importing it as

```
import {CONSTANTS} from '../../services/constants'; //the path is correct
```

However I get the error CONSTANTS not defined in the file where I am importing.. what am i missing here ?

Answer (score 23):

Here is how you should do it:

```
// constants.ts
export const API_ENDPOINT= 'http://localhost:3000/';
```

And importing it as:

```
import * as Constants from '../../services/constants';
```

And you can access it like this:

```
Constants.API_ENDPOINT;
```

Comment: what about if i want to create multiple variables in constant.ts?
1. where do i put it in the project structure
2. how to access single variable from it
thank you

Answer (score 1):

For **Ionic**

```
app.value('config', {
  "constant1": "value1",
  "constant2": "value2"
});
```

and access it with

```
config.constant1
```

> Do not forget to inject dependency `config`.

For **Nativescript**

Define

```
var configObject = {
    testData: false,
    apiUrl: "https://www.domain.com/api/v1/"
};
```

Use

```
var config = require('../../utils/config');
```

and get value

```
config.apiUrl
```

Regards

Comment: I wish you could elaborate more as to where you add this code.  Inside what file?

Answer (score 1):

In my App I created my constant file like bellow,in my main directory of my app **inside filename - "envrionment.ts"**

```
export const environment = {
  site_url : 'http://localhost/wp',
  quotes_url : '/wp-json/wp/v2/quotes',
  jwt_url: '/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token'
}
```

> Then I imported from inside my provider like bellow:

```
import {environment} from '../../envrionment';
```

Hope it helps, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> However I get the error CONSTANTS not defined in the file where I am importing

It works fine. Double check:

- tsconfig.json : have `module` setting set.
- `console.log(CONSTANTS)` in both files to see whats happening