# Global Value Ionic Angular

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

What are the best ways to use global variables in angular ionic? I would like to use the variable in different controllers.

1 of the variable will get the value from firebase and use in different controller. How to do this the simplest way. Thanks!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938380/global-variables-in-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

Use `$rootScope` that will be accessible from multiple controllers. [Ref.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope)

**OR**

use

```
app.value('config', {
    "constant1": "value1",
    "constant2": "value2"
});
```

and access it

```
config.constant1
```

> Do not forget to inject dependency `config` in controller.

my original Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37875001/6449750)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You could share variables between controllers by setting up a service:
Please see:
 [use variable of another controller angularJS with ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37907092/use-variable-of-another-controller-angularjs-with-ionic/37908908#37908908)

Services are the simplest form of sharing variables between controllers, you could also use 'factories' and 'providers' which are more robust in their structure and transfer.