# Configuring API from global javascript variable in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building a web application in AngularJS which uses an API and some parameters

```
var api_params = {
    api_key: "ABCDE12345",
    api_base_url: "/something",
    // ...
}
```

And I am trying to set these properties inside my angular `app` through either `app.value` or `app.constant`, to have it in a clean way.

```
app.value('API_Params', {
    // ...
    // ...
});
```

I am trying to avoid setting these values in hidden inputs

```
<input type="hidden" name="api_key" value="ABCDE12345"/>
<!-- ... ... -->
```

(which I could retrieve with `angular.element($selector)`), and avoid hardcoding the values

```
app.value('API_Params', {
    api_key: "ABCDE12345",
    api_base_url: "/something",
    // ...
}
```

But no matter how much I look for it or tinker with the code, there's always an error.

---

This would be my ideal situation:

In my HTML:

```
<script>
    var api_params = {
        // ... as seen above
    }
</script>
```

And in my angular app

```
myWebApp.value('API_Params', "Something clever here to get api_params");
```

Thank you!

---

Update: I'm trying to avoid bad practices. If you think there are other legit methods, please post your answer with recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.value('config', {
   "constant1": "value1",
   "constant2": "value2"
});
```

and access it with

```
config.constant1
```

> Do not forget to inject `config` in controller

You can refer my original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37875001/6449750).

Comment: In that case have you defined `var` before `app.value` module ?

Comment: Please see the updated/clarified question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly correct your var defintion with `:` not `=`

```
var api_params = {
    api_key: "ABCDE12345",
    api_base_url: "/something"
}
```

TrY sth like this:

```
myWebApp.constant('API_Params',{
    api_key: "ABCDE12345",
    api_base_url: "/something"
});
```

Comment: Please see the updated/clarified question. Thank you

Comment: Using angular constant/value is a good practice in this case. Just inject API_Params in your controller and you can access its data like API_Params.api_key

Comment: My applications uses several controllers, so I believe your approach would mean to "inject" the parameters in each of them?

Comment: Yes it needs to be injected in each controller.
If you would like to use your approach with script inside HTML, then just refer to this variable inside controllers etc. like api_params.api_key

Answer (score 0):

it all depends on how you plan on using api_params.

If you need it to 'live' inside Angular 'world' i.e be used by your angular app then setting it as a value or constant would be a good option, since it can easily be retrieved by your services/controllers and used by your $http service.

If you globally need api_params i.e not only for your Angular app, then it would be a good idea to set those params as a property of 'window' or 'document' objects which are also accessible by your angular app i.e

In your html template:

```
window.api_params = {
  api_key: 'any_api_key',
  ...
};
```

In your Angular app:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp');

app.controller('mycontroller', [$window, function ($window) {
    $window.api_params.api_key = 'new_api_key';
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy, I just define a global variable

```
var api_params = {
    api_key: "ABCDE12345",
    api_base_url: "/something",
    // ...
}
```

and use it in myApp.value or myApp.constant like this:

```
myApp.config("API_Params", api_params)
```

This will make it accessible from all the controllers (e.g. `API_Params.api_key`).

---

My problem was that the global Javascript variable wasn't defined *before* the AngularJS snippet. That is the scripts **should be defined** in this order:

```
<script>
    var api_params = {
        api_key: "ABCDE12345",
        api_base_url: "/something",
        // ...
    }
</script>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
```

But the `angular.js` snippet was placed on top. Unlike `jQuery` or other libraries, `angular.js` doesn't wait for `document.ready()`